# How do I transfer a file over a network and record time taken?

Tags: shell, networking, network-programming, network-protocols, data-transfer

I am writing a paper on networks and I have to set up a lab to collect some data, I am just unsure of how the data I need can be collected.

What I need seems quite simple. I want to transfer a file from one computer to another on the same wireless network, and record how long time this takes. I don't want there to be any encryption only just the file sent to the router and then from the router to the other computer.

I've tried to figure out how to do this and FTP seems obvious, but I am really unsure of how to record the time taken for the transfer.

I am working on Apple computers BTW.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `netcat` which is installed by default on OSX anyway as `/usr/bin/nc`. It has switches to control whether it uses tcp or udp and has zero overhead or logging in or passing filenames and permissions. Being command-line driven, you can easily time it too.

```
nc -l 30000      # Act as a server and listen on port 30000
```

And in a different terminal window:

```
echo Hi | nc localhost 30000    # Send string "hi" to server on localhost port 30000
```

If you want to time file transfers, you can use `dd` to make arbitrarily sized files to send and `time` to time them:

```
nc -l 30000 > /dev/null
```

and

```
time dd if=/dev/zero bs=1m count=1000 | nc localhost 30000   # Send a file of 1,000 blocks of 1MB of zeroes to netcat server and time result.
```

**Note:**

Be careful that you are not reading or writing from/to disk, as your disk can probably only sustain 150MB/s which is of the same order as your network can transfer so your disks will slow the apparent transfer rate. That is why I read from /dev/zero and write to /dev/null because the following test shows that this combination can sustain 17GB/s

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1m count=500000 
500000+0 records in
500000+0 records out
524288000000 bytes transferred in 29.350139 secs (17863220400 bytes/sec)
```

There are some examples of how to use it [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/nc-command-examples/).

Comment: How would I be able to send to a remote server?

Comment: On the local server, use `nc remoteserver 30000` and on the remote server you can listen with `nc -l 30000`

Comment: You may need to go to Apple Menu->System Preferences->Privacy and turn off or adjust the firewall settings.

Comment: Don't forget that bandwidth (i.e MB/s) is not the only metric for network performance... `latency` is also critical for some applications, so you should measure the RTT (round-trip time) for small packets as well as the throughput for large data sets... if you only need 1 byte of acknowledgement and the throughput is 1GB/s but the latency is 7 years...

Answer (score 1):

Most GUI based FTP clients tell you how long the transfer took and what the resulting bandwidth calculation is. In fact, even the most primitive text based FTP clients tell you how many bits have been transfered over how many seconds.

What exactly are you trying to measure by taking the time taken to send files over the network?

There are a lot of things to consider when measuring such things. Never assume that the thing that you are trying to measure is the bottleneck. For example, you could be measuring xMbps over the wireless network thinking that the measured bandwidth is due to the bottleneck of the wireless connection itself, when in fact it's just the CPU on the router that is maxed out. Or you could be measuring the bandwidth of yMbps and later realize that the bottleneck was due to the mechanical 5400rpm hard drive.

Comment: I am evaluating the use of data compression in conjunction with file transfers. More specifically I need to find out when it is beneficial to compress and when it is not. I therefore have to add the compression and decompression times to the time it takes to transfer the file over this two link connection.